# Does Shia Islam have any narration where attributing a lie to the Prophet is a grave sin and leads to hell?

Tags: hadith, shiism, lying

> “Do not tell lies about me, for whoever tells lies about me will enter Hell.” Narrated by [al-Bukhaari, 106](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/3/48).

Sunni Muslims have the above narration which tells about consequences of deliberate lying about the Prophet.

Does Shia Islam have any narration where attributing a lie to the Prophet is a grave sin and leads to hell?

Comment: what's the significance of this question? I mean isn't it obvious that you shouldn't do such—regardless of sect?

Comment: Even outside Islam, calumny is frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

```
           In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

I found a related hadith (religious narration) which might elucidate the inquiry and can be your answer. According to a Motewater (successive) hadith:

> مَنْ‏ کَذَبَ‏ عَلَیَ‏ مُتَعَمِّداً فَلْیَتَبَوَّأْ مَقْعَدَهُ مِنَ النَّارِ

Namely:
**Whoever advertently attributes a lie(s) to me (the Prophet), he/she goes to provide his (her) place in the hell.**

- من لا یحضره الفقیه، ج ‏۴، ص ۳۶۴.
  ([Kitab_man_la_yahduruh_al-faqih_(book)](http://en.wikishia.net/view/Kitab_man_la_yahduruh_al-faqih_(book)))

---

**Source:**

- [http://thaqalain.ir](http://thaqalain.ir/?p=47341#_ftnref1)
- [www.hadithlib.com](http://www.hadithlib.com/rolls/view/1900399/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%B0%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%BA-%D8%A8%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D9%BE%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%89--%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87--%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87--%D9%88--%D8%A2%D9%84%D9%87)

Answer (score 0):

Does the Shiites have a narration that attributing a lie to the Prophet is a great sin and leads to hell?
Imam Sadegh (AS) says: Lying to God and the Prophet (PBUH) is one of the great sins.
Imam Sadegh (AS) quotes from his ancestors: That the Prophet (PBUH) in his will said to Ali (AS): O Ali, whoever lies to me, his position will surely be filled with fire.

Ref: https://hawzah.net/fa/LifeStyle/View/55632/%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%BA-%D8%A8%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%86-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7-%D9%88-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%BA%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85